# Interact with handlebars template after it has loaded

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, templates, handlebars.js

I can pass in variables to a handlebars template using nodejs/express etc.

However, I have a situation that I cannot seem to understand.

1. Person must click on a html element from the handlebars template.
2. I want a js function to be called from this click (not sure where to write this function) that changes the css class of another html element inside that same template.

Can someone please explain if this is possible?

Comment: If your Handlebars templates are rendering on the server, then your client-side code need not know anything about them. The client is dealing with HTML and DOM in the same way as it would no matter if the HTTP response body was rendered with Node, PHP, or straight from a static HTML file. Handlebars isn't relevant to your case. You just need to search for "adding a click handler to an element".

Comment: Ok thanks, I see. I've got it working writing it in script tags underneath the relevant handlebars template. Is it best practice to write js within a handlebars template? Is there a better place to write it?